# Algorithm fewest zip codes to find set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ripped through all of the US Zip Codes and the search results included multiple locations per search.  I would like to now figure out the minimum number of zipcodes I need to search with to return the same unique location results.  e.g. zip code 12345 returns stores A, B, C, D and zip code 12347 returns A,B,C and zip code 12349 returns B, C, D ; I would like to just get 12345 since it gets all of the stores.

Comment: but what is your input parameter based on which 12345 will be returned, i.e. what do you submit as your search criteria?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your tables?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  The data has zip code and then the store data.  I get unique data from the store number.  So basically one zip code returns 0-many stores and then I split them up so I have a table with zip and storeNum that I can tie back to the original table.  I want to be able to refresh the data without going through every zip code again. I think Gordon Linoff's answer will work. I will try it tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have data that has two columns, zipcode and store.  Any given zipcode and store may appear multiple times in the data.

Technically, what you are asking for is a covering set.  Each zip code "covers" a set of stores.  You are looking for the covering set with the minimum size (fewest zip codes).

It is easy to get a covering set.  Here is an example:

```
select distinct zipcode
from (select store, min(zipcode) as zipcode
      from t
      group by store
     ) t
```

A modification of this might get you close to what you want.  For each store, if you choose the zip code that covers the most stores for that zip code, you'll have a greedy algorithm for choosing the covering set.  Here is one way:

```
select distinct zipcode
from (select store, zipcode
      from (select store, zipcode, count(*) as numstores,
                   row_number() over (partition by store order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
            from t
            group by store, zipcode
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1
     ) t
```

The greedy algorithm, though, is not guaranteed to produce the minimum number of zip codes.  Unfortunately, I don't think the general solution to your problem is feasible in SQL, because you need to consider all combinations of zip codes.  And then determine the smallest one that covers all the stores.  The query above, though, may be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: I think the second example is sufficient for what I am trying to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select zip_code,max(stores) from (Select     zip_code,count(1) stores from mytable
Group by zip_code)
```